# Are there licensing restrictions when using MonoMacPackager

Tags: c#, mono, licensing, monomac

I am thinking about writing a program and distributing it through the Mac App Store.  The Mono Project has a library called MonoMac that assists in interfacing native Mac libraries such as Cocoa, etc.  Assuming I go through with this, I would need to distribute Mono with the program.  The process has been streamlined quite nicely and the instructions can be found [here](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager).  Unfortunately I seen nothing concerning licensing on this page.  Any ideas where I can find more information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contact Xamarin [here](http://xamarin.com/licensing) and check with them whether you need a commercial license.

Comment: Contacted Xamarin a few months ago, Miguel replied and cleared it up.  There weren't any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.mono-project.com/License).

IANAL, but AFAIU you would be linking against LGPL libraries. So you can use a proprietary product with them fine, so long you provide to the user of your apps any modification that you did to the LGPL code that you used. (MonoMac [is Apache/MIT](https://github.com/mono/monomac/blob/master/LICENSE) so no problem there either.)

The only problem you would have is if you link to GPL libraries and you don't want to make your app GPL as well (the only ones licensed as GPL are the Mono tools... not sure if mkbundle is one of them but if you just use it to generate your executable, and you don't link to it in any way afterwards, I guess you're fine.)

Anyway, better to do as Strillo says, just in case.

Comment: This answer demonstrates a minimal understand of how the application is distributed. Its just a folder in the app. Users can access and replace this.